# Is it possible for a normal user to flag a Wikipedia edit as potential vandalism?

Tags: wikipedia

I can find vague references from various sources (e.g. on [Talk:Anti-vandalism ideas: Automatic vandalism identification](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Talk%3aAnti-vandalism_ideas#Automatic_vandalism_identification)) implying that Wikipedia edits can be flagged as potential vandalism.  However, I (a normal, non-admin Wikipedia user) don't see any way to flag a given Wikipedia edit as potential vandalism.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't "flag" edits, per se. If you see an edit that is vandalism, you're expected to "rollback" or, at least, edit out the vandalism bits yourself. That's part of Wikipedia's mantra of **Be Bold!**

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Content

> You can edit almost any page on Wikipedia. Simply follow the "Edit" link at the top of that page. [**Be bold**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Be_bold) in improving articles. When adding facts, please [provide references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Introduction_to_referencing/1) so others may verify them. If you are affiliated with the article subject, please see the [conflict of interest guide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Plain_and_simple_conflict_of_interest_guide).

From: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Contact_us_-_Readers

> If you find some incorrect information, there are a few things you can do. First, you can fix it yourself! Anyone can edit Wikipedia. Just hit the "edit" button on the top right of the page, make the correction, and hit "Save page". If you want to learn more about editing, try our help pages.
>
> If you can't or don't want to fix an error, your best approach depends on what kind of problem it is:
>
> - if it's **clear vandalism and you can't fix it**, please email `info-en-v@wikimedia.org` and include the address or title of the article and a description of the issue.

(emphasis mine)

If an account is a serial vandal, there are places to report them so that they can be dealt with.

See:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Reverting
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Vandalism (especially [How to respond to vandalism - for beginners](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Vandalism#For_beginners))

Comment: My use case is that I'm not sure it's vandalism, so the {{dubious}} template (mentioned in How to respond to vandalism - for beginners) is appropriate.

Comment: Disregard my last comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Dubious specifically says it should not be used for unsourced statements

Comment: Unsourced statements should be rolled back (with suitable, non-default edit summary) or use the [{{Citation needed}}](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Citation_needed) template.

Comment: I did the latter (http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Upstream_server&diff=prev&oldid=541020934)

Comment: For that particular edit, you should have just removed the information. People are not supposed to "sign" Wikipedia articles.

Comment: I know, but my theory is that there is a remote possibility that it wasn't vandalism, and that the edit was claiming that the article text was copied from an article or something by Fawad Joya, and I didn't want to just lose that information if that was the case, and I didn't want to take the time to actually determine whether Fawad Joya actually wrote the text and format it as a proper citation, so I made the simplest change I could that marked it as potentially spurious information.

Comment: But it's all academic at this point, since you removed the offending text ;)

Comment: For what it's worth, there is an absolute mountain of information available at Wikipedia for using Wikipedia, not the least of which are the help pages and the Village Pump, for a start. I wouldn't really look for Wikipedia help here.